# Is there a way to make OR conditionals span multiple lines?

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

In a text-based adventure I'm programming, I've been coding IF statements to allow for multiple lines of conditionals, like so:

```
    if certain_input == (
                       "examine bed" or "look at bed" or "look bed" or "look straw" or "inspect straw" or
                       "inspect bed" or "search bed" or "examine straw" or "look at straw"
                      ):
        print("this input has been fulfilled")
```

The only conditionals that work in this format are "examine bed" and "inspect bed". Every other listed option returns an error when used. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: "inspedc bed" does not return True here, only "examine bed"

Answer (score 5):

try putting all these items in a list and using `in`:

```
option_lst = ["examine bed", "look at bed", "look bed", "look straw", "inspect straw", "inspect bed", "search bed", "examine straw", "look at straw"]
certain_input = "look at bed"
if certain_input in option_lst:
    print("this input has been fulfilled")
```

this makes your code easier to change in the future and more elegant.

btw the statement:

```
x = ("examine bed" or "look at bed" or "look bed" or "look straw" or "inspect straw" or
     "inspect bed" or "search bed" or "examine straw" or "look at straw")
```

returns `"examine bed"` since `"examine bed"` is not an empty string and therefore is [truth like](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing), so you'd be only comparing with `"examine bed"`.